# SVN Export error : svn: Can't move tempfile.tmp to c:\xxx folder. Access Denied

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using svn command line to export individual file from svn repository. When I am doing this "Svn export" from my computer where I am the Administrator it works fine (I am exporting files **using svn command line and it's being called from c# program**). But when someone else doing this operation from different computer where the person is not the "Administrator" of the PC, i am getting this error

> SVN Export error : svn: Can't move tempfile.tmp to c:\xxx folder.
>   Access Denied.

only when i am exporting individual file.

I did lots of google search and most of the people are pointing it to Antivirus issues and folder access issues. Since i am working in a controlled environment so I will not be able to "stop" antivirus. Second option is folder permission on the local folder which I have verified and I have the full access to that folder which means it's not a folder access issue.

Could anyone please advise how to resolve this ?

Comment: Try specifying full path with file name instead of just folder: `svn export server/file c:\xxx\file.

Comment: Tried the full path. it turns out to be the issue with svn 1.6 version.